# Expression for the Likelihood Function in Point Estimation

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, maximum-likelihood, point-estimation

I came across this question in my statistics textbook, but I'm struggling to come up with an expression for the likelihood function. Here is the question:

Assume that there are three possible traits for a specimen, namely $K,L,M$, and they occur with probabilities $1-\theta, \theta(1-\theta), \theta^2$ respectively. $\theta$ is unknown, but there are $n$ independent and randomly selected specimen to estimate $\theta$, and they give respectively $X_1, X_2, X_3$ counts for traits $K,L,M$ respectively ($X_1 + X_2+X_3 = n$). How can I express the likelihood function as a function of the parameter and the data?

This is what I came up with:

\begin{align*}
l(\theta) = (1-\theta)^{X_1} \cdot \theta(1-\theta)^{X_2} \cdot \theta^{2X_3}
\end{align*}

I'm not sure if this is true, however. Can someone please point me in the right direction? I would appreciate any help on this!

Comment: $L(\theta) = (1-\theta)^{X_1} \cdot (\theta(1-\theta))^{X_2} \cdot \theta^{2X_3}$ for $\theta\in (0,1)$ is fine. This is a multinomial model.

Comment: Is this a question from a course or textbook? If so, please add the [tag:self-study]
tag & read its [wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).